# recursion sum of subsets keeping getting error message

Tags: c, recursion

I am working on this problem on this online judge site(http://zerojudge.tw/ShowProblem?problemid=a981#). Sorry for that it's only in Mandarin :(.Basically it's a sum-of-subsets-problem.
Keep getting same error message on my submit:

> RE (SIGSEGV)
>   Segmentation fault

My C code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int w[35]= {0};
bool is_included[35]= {false};
bool is_promising(int);
void sum_of_subsets(int,int,int);
int n = 0,W = 0,weight = 0,total = 0,i = 0,j = 0,k = 0,flag = 0,temp = 0;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

    while(scanf("%d %d",&n,&W)==2) {
        memset(w,0,sizeof(w));
        memset(is_included,false,sizeof(is_included));

        total = 0;
        i = 1;
        temp = n;
        while(temp--) {
            scanf("%d",&w[i++]);
        }

        //ascending bubble sort
        for(j = n; j >= 1; --j) {
            flag=0;
            for(k = 1; k < j; ++k) {
                if(w[k]>w[k+1]) {
                    temp = w[k];
                    w[k] = w[k+1];
                    w[k+1] = temp;
                    flag=1;
                }
            }

            if(!flag) {
                break;
            }
        }


        for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
            total+=w[i];
        }

        sum_of_subsets(0,0,total);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool is_promising(int index) {
    return (weight+total>=W)&&(weight==W||weight+w[index+1]<=W);
}

void sum_of_subsets(int index,int weight,int total) {
    int j=1;
    if(is_promising(index)) {
        if(weight==W) {
            for(j=1; j<=index; ++j) {
                if(is_included[j]) {
                    printf("w[%d] = %d\n",j,w[j]);
                }
            }

        } else {
            //include w[index+1]
            is_included[index+1]=true;
            sum_of_subsets(index+1,weight+w[index+1],total-w[index+1]);

            //exclude w[index+1]
            is_included[index+1]=false;
            sum_of_subsets(index+1,weight,total-w[index+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Best advice: use a debugger.

Comment: The global variable `weight` refered from `is_promising` won't be updated throughout the execution and will remain zero as initialized. Try checking implementations around it. You may want to add some parameters to `is_promising` to be passed from `sum_of_subsets`.

Comment: @kaylum I was using GCC Compiler(Code::Blocks IDE)and its debugger with hours of exhaustive debugging...

Comment: Well, then please give us the debugging information. Like the exact stack trace when it crashes. Also, tell us the input that causes the crash.

Comment: @MikeCAT You are right,I also found that weight variable stay unchanged,I'll hava a check over it.

Comment: @kaylum my input is:<br/>10 100<br/>
10 20 40 30 50 80 60 70 5 15<br/>and the application seems frozen,like running in an infinite loop...